# Modifying the default -Prefix.pch file

Tags: ios, xcode

I would like to know how I can modify the default .pch file included with the xcode project templates.

I would like to do that in order to have a few #defines automatically included in all my projects. An example of what I would want to have for all my projects is something like the following for a shared app delegate:

```
#define APP_DELEGATE ((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])
```

I tried searching for a template .pch file within xcode's package with no luck.

If you think it is not a good idea to do this, feel free to tell me why, but please also tell me how I can modify the template if you can, since that is my question.

Comment: That is not really the best place for a preprocessor macro, for many reasons. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_header

Comment: @quellish where would be the best place to put one that, as in my example, I would want to have automatically included in all my projects?

Comment: Create your own project template, and put your macros in a standard ``MyProjectMacros.h`` file that each of your relevant source files includes.

Comment: I am trying to implement exactly the same thing.. which you were trying to implement.. will be thankful if you share the knowledge gained :)

Comment: @7usam .. hey he did not suggest how can you modify the existing pch file, he only guided about the TemplateInfo.plist. I tried to navigate through the plist but did not get any clue about modifying the pch file. If you can elaborate how exactly you implemented your requirement.. it would be of great help :-)

Comment: @Miraaj "Look at the Definitions section of that plist." If you open that plist and explore the Definitions section you will find a string value with the default UIKit import. You can modify that to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default Xcode templates live in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates` . Inside Base/Base.xctemplate you will find a file TemplateInfo.plist . That is what you will have to modify to do what you want. Look at the Definitions section of that plist.

If you want to do this only for iOS, you will instead need to modify the templates in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates`. The structure of the iPhone Base.xctemplate though would not make changing the default prefix header for iOS only easy though.

XCode templates were once straightforward to use and create, since XCode 4 this has not been the case.

I would strongly suggest following some of the information online about creating your own templates instead of modifying those inside Xcode.

[This is one of the best starting points for creating your own templates and learning how templates work](https://github.com/borealkiss/Minimal-Template)

Comment: I tried that by modifying the "global" Base.xctemplate and it worked as I wanted. I will revert that now and try to make my own template. Thanks.