# How to make an Obj-C library globally renameable (every class / exported symbol)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, linker

Working on a large open-source project, we've hit this problem, so this makes a good case study / example:

1. Our library implements SVG spec
2. SVG Spec is *defined* as "including" the DOM and CSS Specs
3. DOM Spec requires a DOM implementation, but Apple refuses to share their DOM implementation on iOS
4. We had to re-implement DOM in ObjectiveC, so we could correctly implement SVG
5. But Apple has accidentally/deliberately put some classes in the global namespace that use the reserved names from DOM. It is impossible for anyone to make a new class with those names

Our current workaround:

1. We rename affected classes from e.g. "Name" to "AppleHasConflictedThisInGlobalNameSpaceName". Yes, it's not the politest of messages, but it explains to newcomers why we've had to deviate from the spec!

With iOS8, Apple's done it again, and added some more classes with this problem, including "Comment". (Apple? Really? Oh, come on, guys! Think before you spam the global space!). This is getting harder to workaround.

---

Normal solution: Since C/ObjC has no namespaces (sob!), we'd prefix every class. SVG Spec has an official prefix - "SVG" - which we use. For non-spec classes, we have a longer prefix that's probably unique to our open-source project.

But for DOM, we are including our own DOM implementation, and it's possible that a developer's project might have a different, proprietary DOM implementation. Sensible prefixes are hard to come up with here. Apple has already reserved "DOM" as a prefix on Obj-C platforms.

If we took the prefix "SVGKitDOM", which would be the smallest correct prefix name, that triples the length of the classnames from DOM (!), and often makes the code unreadable. It's also against Apple's preferenece of 2-3 letter prefixes.

---

The project is open-source, so technically: anyone can global-rename the source to anything they want. But this is a huge pain for people to maintain.

I've been thinking of clever macroing workarounds - e.g. #define OPTIONAL_PREFIX DOM / OPTIONAL_PREFIX SVGKitDOM / ..etc that allows users to quickly rebuild the whole DOM and the dependent SVG libraries in one step with whatever prefix they need.

...but this still seems errorprone and messy. And it'll make new commits a knightmare: we'll have to educate every committer in how to use macros in every classname (if that even works with ObjC).

Argh!

There must be an easier way? Namespace conflicts have been a problem for 30+ years now :).

NOTE: This is Objective-C, so it's a superset of C, but the linking process *is not* a superset - For instance, Apple bans everyone from dynamic linking. So, we need a solution that's static :(.

Comment: The `Comment` struct in OS X is older than SVG, probably going back to when the Mac was introduced in 1984 (or whenever Apple added AIFF support to the classic Mac OS), back then, there were no frameworks, so you could *not* include `<AIFF.h> and be fine. Sadly, with where the AIFF header is, it's impossible to not include it now.  That and C was fairly new back then.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, you could use the not often mentioned `@compatability_alias` attribute, as follows:

File: PrefixedHeader.h

```
@interface my_longly_prefixed_ClassThatDoesSomething : NSObject
@end
```

File: ConvenienceHeader.h

```
@compatibility_alias ClassThatDoesSomething my_longly_prefixed_ClassThatDoesSomething
```

If the user has their own proprietary DOM implementation, then have them not import the convenience headers, otherwise do.

Would this work?

Comment: That is an awesome feature - thanks! It's listed as GCC, which Apple appears to have now dumped / banned (they only allow Apple's proprietary LLVM compiler, as of 2014?), so I'm not sure if this will work any more, but it's a great idea to try.

Comment: Update: appears to work - Apple LLVM 3 is happily building with the @compatibility_alias, although I'm failing to find any docs for this feature, other than the SO.com answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14107519/153422 -- NB I get only 4 hits on Google for this keyword!

Comment: We're going to try this on a couple of smaller cases and report back once it's worked/failed.

Comment: `@compatibility_alias` is a slightly smarter `#define`. You might just use #define instead.